# html2canvas with Proxy

Tags: javascript, php, proxy, html2canvas

I have a page that uses http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ to copy an image in a div. This works great. When I load an external image into the div I add the proxy, this does not work. In my code I simply add "proxy: "/two2/php/proxy.php",":

```
$('.Canvas').html2canvas({
    //logging:true,
    proxy: "/two2/php/proxy.php",
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
```

And then I upload the php https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy/blob/master/html2canvasproxy.php to that folder "/two2/php/".

Is there something else I need to do to get it working?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the proxy there be the full url?

Comment: It definitely getting the proxy.php file I have a var that I removed from the code: proxy: myURL+"/two2/php/proxy.php",

Comment: I do get this in my response:
html2canvas_1("error: html2canvas-proxy-php: The execution time is not configured enough to TIMEOUT in SOCKET, configure this with ini_set\/set_time_limit or \"php.ini\" (if safe_mode is enabled), recommended that the \"max_execution_time =;\" be a minimum of 5 seconds longer or reduce the TIMEOUT in \"define('TIMEOUT', 30);\"");

Comment: Although I have increase it from
define('TIMEOUT', 30);//Timeout from load Socket
to
define('TIMEOUT', 3000);//Timeout from load Socket
and still get that response?

Answer (score 2):

In the PHP I was increasing TIMEOUT I should have been decreasing. It was

```
define('TIMEOUT', 30);//Timeout from load Socket
```

I changed it to

```
define('TIMEOUT', 10);//Timeout from load Socket
```

Now it works